# How to create center buttons using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, button

I know my issue is easy to solve when using HTML, but here is how my buttons are set:

(In a JavaScript file)

```
var myButton=$('<button type="button" style="display:inline">Click</button>');
```

I have 6 buttons, and I would like to center all the buttons (they are put horizontally).

I tried to assign a class to each button, then wrap them in a same `div`:

```
$('.class1, .class2, .class3').wrapAll('<div class="wrap">');
```

And put in my CSS file

```
.wrap {
   text-align: center;
    }
```

But it didn't work.

Actually, I don't need `class1`, `class2`. Is there any other way to wrap all the buttons in a same `div`?

Comment: Well you made them inline....

Answer (score 1):

Well you made them inline....They are doing what you told them to do, be in one line.

Make their `display` as `block` if you want them on their own lines.

Answer (score 0):

Set them to be `inline-block` and set the `width` of wrap to the width of its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Set width and margin to the wrap

```
.wrap{
   width:400px; 
   margin:0 auto;  
}
```

Hope this helps  http://jsfiddle.net/ZHdqK/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button').wrapAll($('<div class = "wrap">'));

.wrap{
    text-align:center;  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rJD2B/